# Corda: How Contract Attachments are being transferred in Transaction?

Tags: corda

The [Using Attachments](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-attachments.html) page states:

> Attachments are ZIP/JAR files referenced from a transaction by hash,
>   but not included in the transaction itself.

However, [API: Contract Constraints page](https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html?highlight=contractattachment#using-contract-constraints-in-transactions) states that:

> The JAR containing the state and contract classes, and optionally its
>   dependencies, are all attached to the transaction.

And there is a code snippet showing how to add the Contract Constraint:

```
transaction.addOutputState(state, constraint = HashAttachmentConstraint(serviceHub.cordappProvider.getContractAttachmentID(CONTRACT_ID)!!))
```

However, while checking out **[HashAttachment](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/c32e3a9e267c44d9a995354dc88464c036eedf33/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/contracts/AttachmentConstraint.kt#L49)** code, I do not see that it contains the internals of Contract Jar file.

My assumption is that we are not transferring the Contract Jar with the Transaction. What happens could be described:

1. During Nodes start-up Corda scans all CorDapps and load jars that consists of Contract classes into local Attachment Storage.
2. Each Output state in the Transaction can have a Contract Constraint.
3. During the verification stage, `verifyConstraints(contractAttachmentsByContract)` will be invoked and those constraints (e.g. HashAttachmentConstraint) will be validated against attachments that Node has in its local storage.

Questions:

1. Does Transaction include the Contract Attachment?
2. Will that Contract Attachment be transferred over the network or attachments from the local attachment storage will be used for verification?
3. What am I missing something in my assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the attachment does not get transferred inside the transaction. The transaction only contains a hash reference to the attachment for data reference purposes. This also means that attachments can be re-used across many transactions as they are maintained off-chain in their own database table.

When a node receives a transaction containing an attachment it has not seen before Corda will automatically fetch the attachment from the counterparty: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-attachments.html#protocol

> Normally attachments on transactions are fetched automatically via the `ReceiveTransactionFlow`.

This transfer will occur without any development effort as long as the attachment is smaller than the maxTransactionSize of the network parameters: https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#network-parameters

> maxTransactionSize: Maximum allowed size in bytes of a transaction. This is the size of the transaction object and its attachments.

Contract attachments at this point are generally pre-distributed and signed by the Cordapp developer and deployed by the owner of the Corda node. At this point in time Cordapps are not generally being programmatically installed.

Comment: Hi. Does that mean the automatic fetching does not apply to contract attachments? Or even contract attachments are automatically fetched and the receiving node need not have the contract jar preinstalled?

Comment: @AshishSinha Contract attachments are automatically fetched by the receiving node if they don't have a copy of the contract jar. However, you must ensure that the contract jar is compatible with the receiving node. Signature Constraints, minimum platform version and schemas compatibility should be considered to ensure the node can run the contract jar.